# Gradle Syncing Problem with Kotlin and Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, gradle, compose-desktop

I'm encountering a syncing issue with `Gradle` while trying to set up a project with `Kotlin` and `Compose Desktop`.

Here's my `build.gradle.kts` file:

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
}
group = "io.crypto"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}
dependencies {
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
}
compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "CryptoGraph"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

and here is `setting.gradle.kts` file:

```
    pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    }

    plugins {
        kotlin("jvm").version(extra["kotlin.version"] as String)
        id("org.jetbrains.compose").version(extra["compose.version"] as String)
    }
}

rootProject.name = "CryptoGraph"
```

here is my `gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
kotlin.code.style=official
kotlin.version=1.9.20
compose.version=1.5.10
```

here is my `gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

and here is the error I'm facing:

```
Build file '/home/mbunderline76/tick-viewer/CryptoGraph/build.gradle.kts' line: 3

Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.9.20'] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.9.20'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.9.20')
Searched in the following repositories:
Google
Gradle Central Plugin Repository
maven(https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev)<83 internal lines>
```

I use `Intellij Idea Ultimate 2023.3.2`

here is my `gradle --version--` command output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-08-17 09:59:03 UTC
Revision:     a773786b58bb28710e3dc96c4d1a7063628952ad

Kotlin:       1.5.21
Groovy:       3.0.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          16.0.1 (Private Build 16.0.1+9-Ubuntu-120.04)
OS:           Linux 6.2.0-39-generic amd64
```

What could be causing this problem, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive troubleshooting, I managed to identify the root cause of the issue. The problem lay within the .gradle/gradle.properties file. I had proxy settings configured there, which interfered with the Gradle plugin resolution process.

To resolve this issue:

- Navigate to your project directory.
- Open the `.gradle/gradle.properties` file in a text editor.
- Locate any proxy-related settings and remove or comment them out.

After making these changes, I was able to successfully sync my Gradle project and resolve the plugin resolution error.

I hope this solution helps others facing a similar issue.